# How to send sms using http api in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sms-gateway

I would like to send sms from my asp.net mvc application using HTTP SMS       API, I got http sms api from clickatell. I tried to integrate it to my  asp.net mvc application, but i am getting an error that says: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" Can you provide me with code that works? Here is my action methods:

```
        // GET: Members/SendSMS
        public ActionResult SendSMS()`enter code here`
        {
        return View();
        }





        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult SendSMS(object sender, EventArgs e, Member     

        member)
        {
        string message = member.Message;
        string cell = member.Cell;

        // use the API URL here  
        string strUrl = "https://platform.clickatell.com/messages     

       /http/send?apiKey=xxxxxxx&to=xxxxxxx&   

        content=xxxxxxxx";
        // Create a request object  
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
        // Get the response back  
        HttpWebResponse response =   

        (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(s);
        string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        s.Close();
        readStream.Close();

        return View("Answer", member);
    }
```

Here is my SendSms view:

```
    @model WebApplicationSMS.Models.Member

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "SendSMS";
    }

   <h2>SendSMS</h2>




  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

  </head>
  <body>
   <div>
    <br /><br />

    <br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {  @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <p> Cell Number: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Cell, new { @class =   
    "form-control" }) </p>
        <p>Message: @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message, new { @class =   

    "form-control", rows = '5' }) </p>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit " />
    }


     </div>
   </body>
   </html> 


   @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   }
```

Any one who can assist? i will appreciate your assistance.

Comment: you probably should not post your api key publicly. if you edit it out it will still be viewable by the edit history.

Comment: If you don't want your api key out in public (which it is, in the edit history), delete this question or ask mods to fix. Not sure if they can...just an idea.

Comment: I renew it, its no longer working.